# Se repite información al almacenar en array c#

Tags: c#, jquery, array

Tengo que generar algo de este estilo:

```
[{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "Porcentaje1"
}, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "Porcentaje2"
}]
```

Pero la cantidad de elementos de ese arreglo es dinámico, todo es resultado de una consulta de SQL, los campos deben tener la misma información menos "valueField" (es el que se llena de forma dinámica).

Esto lo realizo con una función, por la que le mando un arreglo con los valores que llevará valueField (ejemplo: Names ["Porcentaje1", "Porcentaje2",...]

Entonces mi función es la siguiente:

```
var array = new Object();
var res = [];

for (i=1; i<cantNames;i++)
{
    array["ballonText"] = "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>";
    array["fillAlphas"] = 0.9;
    array["lineAlpha"] = 0.2;
    array["type"] = "column";
    array["valueField"] = Names[i];
    res.push(array);
}

result = res;

return result;
```

cantNames es la cantidad de valores que obtengo pero debo excluir el primero.

`Names` se llena de la siguiente forma:

```
var valores = Data;
if(valores.length > 0)
{
   var atributos = [];
   for(var aux in valores[0])
   {
      atributos.push(aux);
   }
   return atributos;
}
else
{
   alert('No hay datos');
   return '';
}
```

Al obtener el resultado me da lo siguiente:

```
  [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "Porcentaje2"
}, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "Porcentaje2"
}]
```

Alguien sabe por qué me está repitiendo el valor de "Porcentaje2"?? Gracias!!!

Comment: No veo problemas en el código para llenar el Array. Seguramente el problema viene de antes, es decir, que Names[i]  ya viene mal llenado.

Comment: He usado el console.log para visualizar qué es lo que contiene Names  pero está correcto =/ viene llenado con los valores que debe traer

Comment: No creo que el problema se encuentre en tu ciclo for, empezaria por revisar lo que devuelve la consulta de SQL y despues me moveria a como se llena Names. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios! He revisado qué me devuelve Names pero está correcto =/ de hecho creo que desde la primera iteración se salta al último valor de Names  y de ahi lo repite =/  

Inclusive lo llené manual sin el ciclo for, es decir usando Names[0], Names[1] y Names[2] pero siempre Names devuelve el mismo resultado

Comment: `Names[0]: 'Porcentaje1' y Names[1]: 'Porcentaje2'`, Sería necesario que modifiques `Names[i - 1];` para considerar la primera posición de tu Array.

Comment: Podrias poner el codigo del query y el codgio que llena el array Names. saludos

Comment: Si claro =) aunque he checado el valor de Names y contiene los valores correctos!

  var valores = Data;
    if (valores.length > 0) {
        var atributos = [];
        for (var aux in valores[0]) {
            atributos.push(aux);
        }
        return atributos;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No hay datos");
        return "";
    }

P.D Data es un object tipo JSON que contiene los nombres de Porcentaje1, Porcentaje2, etc. junto con sus respectivos valores, lo que hago con esa parte del código es obtener los "titulos".

Cosa que si queda correctamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no se encuentra en el llenado sino en las referencias de objetos del arreglo al que haces una copia, mueve la linea `var array = new Object();` dentro del ciclo for para que tu copia de el arreglo finalizado `result = res` tenga las referencias correctas, de otra forma se queda solo con las referencias del ultimo elemento empujado al arreglo.

```
var res = [];

for (i=1; i<cantNames;i++)
{
    var array = new Object();
    array["ballonText"] = "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>";
    array["fillAlphas"] = 0.9;
    array["lineAlpha"] = 0.2;
    array["type"] = "column";
    array["valueField"] = Names[i];
    res.push(array);
}

result = res;

return result;
```

Saludos

Comment: :o!! por Dioosss!! MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!! te debo la vida! jejejeje en realidad era eso!

Comment: Por nada, que tengas excellente día, Saludos